# What is the best type of plastic to store alcohol?

Tags: storage-method, alcohol

What kinds of food-grade plastic is best for storing alcohol for cooking use? Does the type of plastic differ based on the percentage of alcohol?

My question actually comes from wanting to brew alcohol in an area that has no access to glass for storage purposes (rural Tanzania), but **does** have access to food grade plastics.

Comment: A similar question will be asked for SE Homebrewing but it could benefit this group as well

Comment: 2 liter bottles are often used for brewing.  If you seal them, don't forget to release the pressure as it builds.

Answer (score 2):

In the United States and Canada much of the plastic bottles used to package alcohol are made with PET (polyethylene terephthalate). I also know it is used in Europe.
This site may be useful - https://www.creativemechanisms.com/blog/everything-about-polyethylene-terephthalate-pet-polyester

I believe some bottles are'laminated' with several different plastics and PET being the 'contact' layer.

I have been told that plastic beverage bottles have a relatively short shelf life, but never had reason to research this.

Anyroad, this information might provide a starting point for your project